# Laravel Eloquent Errors

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Hi everyone  how are you all, i have some issues with PHP and Laravel exactly  in Eloquent Laravel.
My Questions is how can i convert this SQL what i have made in phpmyadmin to laravel ELoquent, whit not errors cause i have got a lot of erros trying to get the solution.

```sql
SELECT users.registrante, users.id,  Sum(1) AS Cant
FROM users
GROUP BY users.registrante
ORDER BY SUM(1) DESC;
```

it works in phpmyadmin, but i have no idea how can i convert to laravel.

first error

```php
$historial = User::select('users.id, users.registrante')
    ->orderBy('sum(1)','DESC') 
    ->groupBy ('users.registrante') 
    ->get();
```

the message from this error

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'users.id, users.registrante' in 'field list'

Hi and i hope you can help me with this :)

Comment: Please [edit] to show the Laravel code you've attempted, and the exact error message you get (as text, not images).

Comment: first error   $historial=User::select('users.id, users.registrante')
        ->orderBy('sum(1)','DESC')
        ->groupBy ('users.registrante')
        ->get();

Comment: the message from this error SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'users.id, users.registrante' in 'field list'

Answer (score 0):

Forget it guys, i got it
it work with this code

```
$historial = User::groupBy('registrante')
```

->selectRaw('sum(1) as sum, registrante')
->get(); //this return collection

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).